# What is :not(style) ~ :not(style) in CSS?

Tags: css, material-ui

Mui automatically added a **:not(style) ~ :not(style)** which I needed an !important to override in my sx.

```
.css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root > :not(style) ~ :not(style) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.css-d13d9m-MuiStack-root {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

What is this **:not(style) ~ :not(style)** ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: *Select every element that is not a style-tag which is also not preceded by a style-tag*. This essentially enables the override of `<head>`  CSS with inline CSS, but only the first element after the inline style. Neat little trick to override main CSS with inline CSS on the fly. Rather opaque too, as you noticed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This selector will apply it's styles to all elements that are not a `style` in the `.css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root` element and and are preceded by another element that is not a `style` element:

```css
.css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root > :not(style) ~ :not(style) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root">
    <style></style>
    <style></style>
    <p>Will not be targeted</p>
    <p>Will be targeted</p>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use `!important`, you could also use the same selector again:

```
.css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root,
.css-1rb8ayf-MuiStack-root > :not(style) ~ :not(style) {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I didn't realise that the "style" in :not(style) refers to an element=style.  But I don't use a style element in my MUI, then how would this apply ? and given it's high priority that I have to use !important ?

Comment: @EBDS I'm not entirely sure what MUI expects in that element, but they want to style all elements that are not a `<style>` or after a `<style>`. It prevents an element getting a margin top when there is a `<style>` before it. The high priority has to do with [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), which is pretty anoying when you're not aware of it, but reading that page I linked will help you understand!

Comment: "and are not preceded by another style element" - No. That should be "and are preceded by another element that is not a style element".

Comment: @Alohci You're right. I've updated the answer